# Laravel: How to add a column to a query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need you help. I'm trying to add a column to each query of an specific eloquent model.

Basically I want to add this:

```
COALESCE(name, network_name) AS name
```

It's important to keep the previously selected fields so I tried this in my model:

```
public function newQuery()
{
    $query = parent::newQuery()->addSelect('name'); // it's name only for testing purposes

    return $query;
}
```

But this doesn't add the column. It replaces it. So instead of getting something like:

> select *, `name` from `programs` where `programs`.`id` = ? limit 1

I get:

> select `name` from `programs` where `programs`.`id` = ? limit 1

What am I doing wrong? I haven't found anything on the net so I really hope you can help me!

Comment: You should select on per query basis. What addSelect will do is add columns to your query.

Comment: Thanks but I don't quite understand. I want to add a column to the query. Every time. So if I make something like Program::get(array('col1')) I need to automatically add another column in the model before the query gets executed.

Comment: I would suggest to do it manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by prady00, you'll have to implement a function in your Eloquent Model as such:

```
public static function getMore()
{
     return self::select('*',DB:Raw('COALESCE(name, network_name) AS coalesce_name'))->get();
}
```

**OR**

Implement an Accessor:

```
protected $appends = array('coalescename');

public function getCoalescenameAttribute()
{
    return ($this->name !== '' ? $this->name : $this->network_name);
}
```

I'll go with the accessor implementation by preference.

Comment: Thank you! Lagbox from laravel chat has suggested an assessor, too and I also think this is the best solution.

Comment: How is that 1st solution supposed to work anyway? If you'd want something like this, then use `scopes`

Comment: accessor thanks! i was not putting the `$appends` property no wonder my accessor could not pop up